# What files are published when using Click Once deployment?

Tags: c#, winforms, clickonce

When I click "Publish" in my project properties, what files are actually getting published?  I spent some time yesterday searching MSDN, but didn't find a clear answer.

I assumed (perhaps incorrectly) that it was publishing the latest version in source control, so I always made sure I had my changes checked in before clicking "Publish".  But now I'm highly suspicious, based on a bug that was reported, that it has been publishing the `Debug` configuration on my laptop.  I have code that should only execute in debug mode (`#if DEBUG`...), and it seems to be executing that code in production.

This is my first WinForms application and first time using ClickOnce deployment. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

1. What code is getting published? Latest in source control, most
   recent build on build server or from local machine?
2. What settings do I need to set (and where are they) to ensure that my
   application is published using the `Release` configuration?

TIA

---

**UPDATE(S):**

Here is what I see on the Publish tab
[image: Here is what I see on the Publish tab (VS2013)]

Does the Build tab come into play at all?
[image: Here is what I see on the Build tab (VS2013)]

The Configuration setting on the Build tab is what matters when Publishing, correct? Not the selection in the toolbar?
[image: Build tab, configuration]

Comment: I believe with clickonce win forms programs, it will publish what ever you have set in your configuration. In VS near the top, you should see a little drop down next to the run button. Change that to `Release` and then publish it.

Comment: Ahhhh, you have the "Define DEBUG constant" checked. Uncheck that.

Comment: @mituw16, please see my latest update to the original post asking for clarification

Comment: @CDR12 , Yes that setting does matter. You need to set Release to be your active configuration then publish it.

Comment: The setting in the toolbar of visual studio is simply a solution configuration.   You can see the specific build properties of each project by opening up the configuration manager. Ultimately, what is set in the build tab is what gets compiled/published.

Comment: Thank you everyone.  I just published an update, waiting for confirmation from end user (I can't test the fix myself in prod - it's department specific)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ASP.NET applications, when you go to publish, there will be a configuration option under settings:

[image]

The code you have locally is what gets compiled and published through Click Once. For non ASP.NET applications, the build configuration selected in visual studio is what ultimately gets published.

For this specific case, you have "Define DEBUG constant checked". That will cause the code marked as #DEBUG to be executed. It doesn't matter what the build configuration is if that is checked.

Comment: The screenie that you attached is only for web projects.

Comment: Both Tim & @mituw16 were big contributors in helping me resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

I tried on some settings on my project.

1) Select *Configuration Manager* by right clicking on your Solution.

[image: Configuration Properties]

2) When i clicked publish, here is what i get in output window

[image: Published release version.]

3) If you want to control what files (dependencies) are included as part of deployment, this can be controlled from *Application Files* button on the publish tab of project properties. 
Here is an image.

[image]

Hope that helps.